# "Force Close" Error on declaring TextView and ToggleButton

Tags: android, textview, togglebutton

Well basicly I have a textview and when the application is created it sets a string as the textviews text not hard, but I get a force close error when I run the app on my phone.

```
TextView sdcard=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.sd_textview);
sdcard.setText(R.string.not_mounted);
```

Then I have a error on a togglebutton also

```
ToggleButton silent=(ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.silentbutton);
silent.setChecked(false);
```

And I have errors for all my other buttons/textviews can anyone help, please?!

EDIT:
I cant post pics because I am a new member, :( 
Link to imgshack http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/849/unledggp.png/

If code for the whole textview snippet.

```
if     (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_UNMOUNTED)) {

TextView sdcard=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.sd_textview);
sdcard.setText(R.string.not_mounted);

}
```

OnCreate Function

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);

checkSD();
checkRing();
checkWifi();
checkBt();

}
```

Comment: can you plz add the Logcat errors , ??

Comment: Post Logcat message and layouts. Did you call `setContentView()`?

Comment: Can you post the rest of the method that those snippets appear in as well as your layout? It's difficult to help with this little information. This usually happens because `findViewById` returned `null`, which means that a view with the given ID was not found. Without more context it will be hard to determine why.

Comment: I can't add logcat pictures because I am new.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look for all instances of `sd_textview` and make sure the one that you're trying to reference is a `TextView`. If you want more clarity you can debug your code and see what object is actually being returned by not casting into a `TextView`:

```
View sdcard = findViewById(R.id.sd_textview); //debug this
//you can also log the View object to see the type 
Log.d("Test", "" + sdcard);
```

Comment: Could you explain more how I could debug just the setText?

Comment: Are you using Eclipse? You can add breakpoints (double click on the left margin on the line in question), then "debug" your project (vs plain "run"), its the bug icon next to the play icon. Once your code reaches that point, the debugger will pop up and you can view the value stored in the `sdcard` View.

Comment: Ahhh yes, when it executes the setText for sdcard it says, that sdcard cannot be resolved....how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your error log (assuming its the right error log) you have a ClassCastException in the `checkWifi` method. Edit your question and include ALL of the `onCreate` method and all of the `checkWifi` method, but I expect you are using the same id for multiple views.

Comment: Okay I will ad it to the main post

Answer (score 0):

Two things I can think of (although seeing more code would help).

Make sure you have called `setContentView(R.layout.main)` (or whatever your layout file is called). Do this BEFORE any attempt to use `findViewById(...)`.

Secondly `sdcard.setText(R.string.not_mounted);` in this statement `R.string.not_mounted` is a resource ID (int) and not a string. You would need to use...

```
sdcard.setText(getString(R.string.not_mounted));
```

Comment: I still get and force close even with the getString

Comment: @Ciehanski: Post your main.xml

Comment: I checked it, it has the sd_textview declared. Same as in the R.java/